# Linq where based on List of integers

Tags: c#, linq

I have a win forms application where we are filtering based on numerous criteria.  One is a multi select dropdown.  This value is an integer and I am having getting the command to work.

I tried the below, but cannot use a contains on an integer.  just showing here so I can give you an idea on what I would like to do.

```
    private List<int> GetSelectedIntVals()
    {
        List<int> intVals = new List<int>();
        foreach (var item in ddlSearchQueueStage.CheckBoxItems)
        {
            if (item.Checked == true)
            {
                intVals.Add(st.GetStageNumberFromText(item.Text));
            }
        }
        return intVals;
    }


    public void FilterBatch(SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
    {
        var FilteredBatch = (from t in BatchList select t).ToList();

        // This is where having issue
        FilteredBatch = FilteredBatch.Where(p => p.Stage.Contains(searchCriteriaQueue.stageVal).ToList();  
        .
        .
        .
        .
        RebuildScreen();
    }
```

Thanks in advance.  I have looked and tried a few other options but have not been able to get working.

Comment: All those `ToList()` calls do nothing other than hurt your performance.

Comment: Can you give us a simplified version of what you are trying to achieve...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `searchCriteriaQueue.stageVal` is a collection of integers (since you say it's a multi-select dropdown), you just have the `Contains` call backwards:

```
    FilteredBatch = FilteredBatch.Where(p => searchCriteriaQueue.stageVal.Contains(p.Stage)).ToList();
```

Comment: I would say that it is good practice to make sure the capture in your lambda to be of system types when possible. You could get problems with Linq providers like Entity Framework.

Comment: That did the trick.  It seems confusing is the fact that I would expect the List values to be in the contains clause.

Comment: It makes sense to ask if a _value_ "contains" a _list_?  I would call that `IsContainedIn`.